# Injected event listeners in Vue JS project don't always fire on page change

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm working with a Nuxt JS / Vue JS app with dynamic pages. My pages fetch data from a remote api which includes HTML and JS that needs to be executed.

In my context, I have a bunch of accordions, that when tapped should open the contents, so in the `then` block of my axios request I'm creating a script tag on the page with the contents:

```js
const string = "some JS from api"
const injectTo = document.querySelector('[data-beam-injectes-interactivity]')
const script = document.createElement('script')
script.innerHTML = string
injectTo.appendChild(script)
```

The string of JS injected is:

```js
function initDeviceGroupCollapses () {
  const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-toggle="collapse"]')
  if (buttons) {
    for (const [index, button] of buttons.entries()) {
      if (button) {
        button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
          event.stopPropagation()

          const target = event.target.dataset.target

          if (!target) {
            return
          }

          const collapse = document.querySelector(target)
          collapse.style.display = collapse.style.display == 'none' ? 'block' : 'none'
        }, false)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The issue I'm having though is that if the JS is injected into a page where the HTML doesn't initially exist, the event listeners no longer fire on `data-toggle="collapse"`.

How can I always make sure that the injected JS works?

Comment: This sounds like an interesting issue. I wonder if the events can not get added since the page does not technically exists yet. Can you print all events for this specific page in question on load and see if anything logs? `console.table(listAllEventListeners());`

Comment: You should probably write it in an imperative way (more Vue-y) rather than using query selectors.

Comment: I think the answer is dependent on where this `initDeviceGroupCollapses` is being called. If you're calling this within the context of Vue (e.g., within a Vue component to manipulate Vue template), this approach of DOM manipulation could fail, especially if the component needs to be re-rendered.